# .load callback function works sometimes?

Tags: php, jquery

My image gallery has next and previous links, when the user click on either one it loads an image in the #the_image div, but I need the image resize everytime.  My thinking I would put the code to resize the image as a callback function for the .load. But's it doesn't work everytime.  Odd thing also, if I put an `alert("blah");` after `image = $('#the_image');` the image get's positioned correctly every time. Any ideas?

Here's my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#previous').live('click', function(e){
     $('#img_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #container',function () {
      var height = $(window).height();
      var width = $(document).width();
      var image = $('#the_image');  
      $("#the_image").css("max-height",height-200); 
      image.css({
       'max-height': height-200,     
       'left': width/2 - (image.width() /2)-5,
       'top': height/2 -(image.height() /2),
      });
      prev = $('#previous'); next = $('#next');
      prev.css({
       'left': 0,
       'top': (height/2)-150,
      });
      next.css({
       'left': 924,
       'top': (height/2)-150,
      }); 
     });     
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }); 
});  
</script>
```

**This is what works. Thanks to Jasper, had to modify his code a bit:**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).delegate('#next', 'click', function (e) {
        $('#img_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #container',function () {

            var height = $(window).height(),
                width  = $(document).width();

            $("#the_image").bind('load', function() {
               var image = $('#the_image'); 
               $("#the_image").css("max-height",height-200); 
               image.css({
                  'max-height': height-200,  
                  'left': width/2 - (image.width() /2)-5,
                  'top': height/2 -(image.height() /2),
               });
            });

            $('#previous').css({
                'left' : 0,
                'top'  : ((height / 2) - 150),
            });

            $('#next').css({
                'left' : 924,
                'top'  : ((height / 2) - 150),
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image has to load before you can get it's width/height.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).delegate('#previous', 'click', function (e) {
        $('#img_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #container',function () {

            var height = $(window).height(),
                width  = $(document).width();

            //here's the fix, we wait for the image to load before changing it's dimensions
            $("#the_image").bind('load', function (
                $(this).css({
                    'max-height' : (height - 200),
                    'left'       : (width / 2 - ($(this).width() / 2) - 5),
                    'top'        : (height / 2 - ($(this).height() / 2)),
                });
            });

            $('#previous').css({
                'left' : 0,
                'top'  : ((height / 2) - 150),
            });

            $('#next').css({
                'left' : 924,
                'top'  : ((height / 2) - 150),
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Alternatively I would use a different AJAX function so you can add the `load` event handler to the image before it is added to the DOM (to make sure you can capture the `load` event before it fires):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).delegate('#previous', 'click', function (e) {
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function (serverResponse) {

            var height = $(window).height(),
                width  = $(document).width();

            //here's the fix, we wait for the image to load before changing it's dimensions
            serverResponse = $(serverResponse).find('#container');
            serverResponse.find('#the_image').bind('load', function (
                $(this).css({
                    'max-height' : (height - 200),
                    'left'       : (width / 2 - ($(this).width() / 2) - 5),
                    'top'        : (height / 2 - ($(this).height() / 2)),
                });
            });

            //add the new HTML to the DOM, `.load()` did this automatically
            $('#img_wrapper').html(serverResponse);

            $('#previous').css({
                'left' : 0,
                'top'  : ((height / 2) - 150),
            });

            $('#next').css({
                'left' : 924,
                'top'  : ((height / 2) - 150),
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried your suggestions but the image isn't  being positioned correctly.

Comment: Can you post a link to the problem page so I can see the behavior?

Comment: OK cool. Got it working, had to work out the math a bit, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and remember height and width are properties not methods:
Also, don't store objects into variables unless you're going to do more work than dot chaining only once per event fire. Oh and I also forgot... the +"px" will really help for IE!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body #main #wrapper').on('click', '#previous' function(e){
     $('#img_wrapper').find("img").attr("src", $(this).attr('href') + ' #container');
      var height = $(window).height(), width = $(document).width();
      $('#the_image').css({
       'max-height': parseInt((height-200), 10)+"px",     
       'left': parseInt((width/2 - (image.width /2)-5), 10)+"px",
       'top': parseInt((height/2 -(image.height /2)), 10)+"px",
      });
      $('#previous')css({
       'left': 0,
       'top': parseInt( ((height/2)-150), 10)+"px",
      });
      $('#next'.css({
       'left': 924+"px",
       'top': parseInt( ((height/2)-150), 10)+"px",
      }); 
     });     
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }); 
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Where do `image.width` and `image.height` come from? Also if you want to get the height of a DOM element with jQuery, this is the proper syntax: `$(document).width()`, the function won't run if you don't add the `()`.

Comment: @Jasper yeah I'll edit. I'm mixing pure JS with jQuery my bad.